# Is there a way to have Java classes generated by the Google protocol buffer compiler declare that they implement an interface?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a bunch of messages that all have a field with the same name and type:

```
message Common {
    string name = 1;
    int age = 2;
}

message Foo {
    Common common = 1;
    int foo_a = 2;
    string foo_b = 3;
    string foo_c = 4;
}

message Bar {
    Common common = 1;
    int bar_x = 2;
    int bar_y = 3;
    string bar_z = 4;
}

message Baz {
    Common common = 1;
    string baz_q = 2;
    int baz_r = 3;
    string baz_s = 4;
}
```

In my Java code I'd like to be able to have a method that can take a
`Foo.Builder`, `Bar.Builder`, or `Baz.Builder` as a parameter, and (sometimes)
calls `setCommon` on this supplied builder.

These three generated classes already have a  `setCommon` method with compatible
signatures, so the easiest way to do this seems like it would be to have an
interface they all implement:

```
interface HasCommonBuilder {
    HasCommonBuilder setCommon();
}
```

Is there a way to specify that these classes should all declare that they implement an interface?